# $X$ is normally distributed with mean $10$ & varience $4$, find $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a<X<b) =0.90$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random variable that is normally distributed with mean $10$ and varience $4$, find the value $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a<X<b) =0.90$ and $| mean -a |= |mean - b|$

my approach:

mean$= 10$

standard deviation$=2$

$P(z)=0.9$
$P\left(  \frac{a-10}2 <z< \frac{b-10}2 \right) =0.9$

I know how to use a normal distribution table but struggling with such problem . How to tackle such problem, kindly looking for help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\Phi(x)$ is

$\Phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} dt$.

If you use MATLAB, you can call the function of "$norminv$" to get $a$ and $b$ as:

> > $S = norminv([0.05; 0.95], 10, 2);$

where $S(1)$ is $a$, and $S(2)$ is $b$.

Answer (score 0):

We want $a$ and $b$ to be symmetrical about the mean.

Hence we have $\Phi\left(\frac{a-10}2 \right)=0.05$ and $\Phi\left(\frac{b-10}2 \right)=0.95$.

I will leave the task of reading of the normal distribution table to you and then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: why 0.05 and 0.95 , may you please explain sir

Comment: We want the region below the normal curve from $\frac{a-10}2$ to $\frac{b-10}2$ to be $0.9$ and we want it to be symmetrical. Hence we have $5\%$ remaining on the right and $5\%$ remaining on the left. This corresponds to $0.05$ and $0.95$.

Comment: What is this phi function, sir may you please explain by solving just 'a' value, will be of huge help, thanks a lot for your kind answer

Comment: It is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: $\phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} dt$.

Comment: Technically this is answer is correct, but it can be simplified to just evaluating and solving through z-scores (ie. $\frac{x - \mu}{S.D}$ = standard normal score)

Comment: reading the normal distribution means solving through $z$-score right?